# Should web farms be concerned with TLS handshake overhead

Tags: web-hosting, tls, protocols, web-farm

I have a web farm where the web servers are responsible for negotiating the secure connections. Does anyone else with a web farm go out of their way to reduce TLS handshake overhead by ensuring that [TLS resume handshakes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Resumed_TLS_handshake) are supported?  And if so, why?

We are switching from a sticky session to a more balanced load balancing algorithm.  We are concerned that we will lose the benefit of the TLS resume feature. 
Assuming every connection from a client goes to a different webserver, we are assuming a full TLS handshake will be required.  I don't know the overhead, but if we are looking at 20ms round trip it would appear that the full handshake will take 3x or so as long to complete.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how large the OPs web server farm is, but for most smaller / midsized installations I find it cleanest and simplest to handle all TLS/SSL on the load balancer. So you have:

```
Internet (HTTPS req) -> L7 HTTPS proxy LB -> plain HTTP on LAN -> webserver
```

o3 Magazine had a good [writeup on how relatively easy this is with nginx](http://www.o3magazine.com/4/a/0/2.html), and what performance numbers you can expect. f5 posted a [commentary on the benefits of using a commercial appliance for SSL acceleration](http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/macvittie/archive/2009/04/17/dear-slashdot-you-get-what-you-pay-for.aspx) instead of a DIY solution (IMHO somewhat biased).

Note that you'll need your web servers to inspect **X-Forwarded-For** and **X-FORWARDED_PROTO** headers and handle the connection correctly.

Most installations should get by fine with a single HTTP & HTTPS load balancer, or a pair of load balancers in active/passive configuration for HA. In this setup **handshake resume is a non-issue**, as there is only one SSL/TLS endpoint (which typically will automatically support handshake resume).

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that one the connection had been established, even with a load-balancer in place, all future connecitons in that session would happen to the same server?

Perhaps that's merely how sites I've used and services I've configured operate.

Comment: Your impression is incorrect.  Every request from a web browser can potentially be routed to any distinct server in the farm.  The only exception are requests made in quick succession may benefit from HTTP's keep-alive mechanism.  In order for requests to be routed back consistently to the same server, a load balancer needs to perform some magic, such as injecting a cookie into the first response to tell it which server to re-route to on subsequent requests.  We call such a LB feature "sticky sessions".

Comment: Then that's how systems I've worked-with have been configured :) ..thanks for the added info

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Apache, have a look at [distcache](http://distcache.sourceforge.net/). From the man page, "the distcache architecture provides a protocol and set of accompanying tools to allow applications, and indeed machines, to share session state between them by way of a network service."

"The primary use of distcache right now is SSL/TLS session caching. This allows SSL/TLS servers (eg. a secure Apache web server providing HTTPS support) to use a centralised session cache, i.e any server may resume SSL/TLS sessions negotiated by any other server on the network. The advantages to this approach include increased freedom of mechanisms for load-balancing."